# Install Sublime silently

Tags: windows, powershell, sublimetext3

I have used both below commands but it asks a next wizard during installation:

```
start-process -FilePath 'C:\Users\suganthanraj.p\Downloads\Sublime Text Build 3126 x64 Setup.exe' -ArgumentList '/qn+

msiexec /quiet 'C:\Users\suganthanraj.p\Downloads\Sublime Text Build 3126 x64 Setup.exe'
```

Comment: You could use the portable version for this; it's just a zip file. You could write a script to extract it where you want to install at, remove the `Data` directory inside (to unportable-ize it) and then modify the registry yourself. However you would have to provide your own uninstall in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

` Here i found answer for my question

**start-process -FilePath 'C:\Users\suganthanraj.p\Downloads\Sublime Text Build 3126 x64 Setup.exe' -ArgumentList '/VERYSILENT'**

Comment: " /VERYSILENT " argument is used to install sublime silenly without User Interaction

Answer (score 1):

There is a c[hocolatey Sublime 3 package](https://chocolatey.org/packages/SublimeText3) which you can use to install Sublime:

```
choco install sublimetext3
```

Answer (score 1):

Sublime Text silent install with context menu **enabled**:

```
start-process -FilePath 'C:\Downloads\Sublime_Text_Build_3143_x64_Setup.exe' -ArgumentList '/VERYSILENT /TASKS="contextentry"'
```

Just need to add to the end line: **'/VERYSILENT /TASKS="contextentry"'**

If you have Chocolatey use this for install silently:

```
choco install -y sublimetext3
```